# Is there a way to connect or access my `scrollView`from my main class to another class?

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

in my MainViewController I have a `scrollView` and add a `ChildView` in it which works fine. In this example I instantiate my `PlansViewController2`and add it as a `ChildView`to my `scrollView`.

[image]

After selecting a `Cell`it pushes a new controller. But I want to add the new Controller as a `ChildView` to my `scrollView.

[image]

---

```
  @IBAction func planAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let newPlan = sender.frame.origin.x
    scrollView.subviews.forEach{$0.removeFromSuperview()}
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let nextController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlansViewController2") as! PlansViewController2
    addChildView(viewController: nextController, in: scrollView)
    self.movingView.frame.origin.x = newPlan
}
```

---

Im my `PlansViewController2` I push another `ViewController`but I want to add it also in my `scrollView` from the previous controller.

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)
            let planViewCtrl = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlanViewCtrl") as! PlanViewController
            planViewCtrl.navigationItem.title = plan.title
            self.show(planViewCtrl, sender: self)
            _ = planViewCtrl.view // force view loading, so we can set it up properly
            _ = self.updateLastUsed(plan: plan)
            planViewCtrl.plan = plan
```

---

Is it possible to add - in my case here - the `PlanViewController` into my `scrollView`from my `MainViewController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add view's PlansViewController2 to scrollview. Please add PlansViewController2 to childViewController of VC has scrollView(`self.addChild(nextController)`).
When you want to add PlanViewController to scrollView:

- Step 1: First you need to get viewcontroller that have scrollView using `parent` property (`self.parent`).
- Step 2: Final, You have access to scrollView instance though vc you get in step 1.

Good luck!

Comment: I accessed my scrollView with ```self.addChildView(viewController: plansViewCtrl, in: self.projectOverViewTabController.scrollView)```but I always get a nil-Error back

Comment: @Preefix Did you `add PlansViewController2 as child controller` yet? Please follow 2 above step to get viewcontroller has scrollview.

Comment: Where do I have to add my `PlansViewController2`as a child? And do I have to use `self.parent.addChildViewController()`?

Comment: Add `self.addChild(nextViewController)` above line `addChildView(viewController: nextController, in: scrollView)`. And from PlansViewController2 you can call `self.parent` to get parentVC has scrollview.

Comment: In my `PlansViewController2`I instantiate `let projectOverViewTabController = ProjectOverViewTabController2()`right? and then I add my child with: `self.addChild(nextViewController)`and `addChildView(viewController: nextController, in: scrollView)`?

Comment: @Preefix I'm confusing, in quesion from PlansViewController2 you want to add `PlanViewController` to scrollview, but in comment is another class.

Comment: @Preefix In PlansViewController2, You want to add `ProjectOverViewTabController2` to scrollview in PlansViewController2's parentView?

Comment: I want to add my `plansViewCtrl` from the `PlansViewController2` class to the `scrollView`from `ProjectOverViewTabController2``

Comment: suppose, ViewController contain scrollview has name `MainViewController`. In `@IBAction func planAction(_ sender: UIButton)` you add code `self.addChild(nextController)` to above of line `addChildView(viewController: nextController, in: scrollView)`. And in `PlansViewController2` you want to add `PlanViewController ` to scrollview in `MainViewController`. You can code follow `let planViewCtrl = PlanViewController()` `let mainVC = self.parent as! MainViewController` `mainVC.addChildView(viewController: planViewCtrl, in: mainVC.scrollView)`

Comment: @Preefix Does it work? Do you understand that comment.

Comment: It worked with: `let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)
                let plansViewCtrl = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlansViewController2") as! PlansViewController2`insttead of `let planViewCtrl = PlanViewController()``

Comment: Congratulation :D

Comment: I forgot to ask something: When I select a cell I have no chance to navigate back. I have to go the the beginning. It is annoying when I am 4 structures forward and only want to move 1 back. Is it possible to add a navigation so that I can get back 1 structure?

Comment: @Preefix If you add viewcontrollers to scrollview. You can set contentOffsetX you calculate at page you want to back. Ex if you add 4 vc to scrollview. A page size is 320px. When press back, You set offsetX at 640.

Comment: I don´t get your point I am sorry. How does changing the contentOffSet.x help here?

Comment: I think viewcontrollers in your scrollview side by side horizontal. If you want to back, just update content offset to scroll previous page.